# Examples of Groups (resp. Rings, Fields, etc.) Which Are Isomorphic to a Proper Subgroup (resp. Subring, Subfield, etc.)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, infinite-groups

Was just reading this question
[When is a group isomorphic to a proper subgroup of itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233700/when-is-a-group-isomorphic-to-a-proper-subgroup-of-itself)
and was wondering not about the conditions for being isomorphic to a proper subgroup, subring, etc., but about examples of these things happening. (Certainly one necessary condition is that our algebraic object be infinite as a set. Otherwise we cannot have a bijection between the initial set and a proper subset.)

I believe one example was given in the above link using even powers of a polynomial ring $R[x]$ and the ring $R[x]$ itself. I *believe* another example is in Dummit and Foote with the roots of unity or something like this. Anyway, have at it!

(Here is another related post: [Rings with isomorphic proper subrings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140905/rings-with-isomorphic-proper-subrings))

(Feel free to also post answers with maybe manifolds which are homeomorphic/diffeomorphic/biholomorphic to proper submanifolds or things like that if you have some favorites!)

(The only category which I know *excludes* this business is algebraic geometry...but only kinda if you deal with incomplete intersections...)

Comment: Maybe the simplest example is $\mathbb{Z} \cong n\mathbb{Z}$ as group?

Comment: The well-known field $\mathbb{C}$ has proper subfields isomorphic as fields to $\mathbb{C}$. (Unlike the field $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: @rschwieb, if I understand you, my answer would be that the reals-of-$D$ are not the reals of $\mathbb{C}$. The degree of $D$ over the $\mathbb{R}$ of your pic will be infinite.

Comment: @ancientmathematician An explicit description of the construction would probably help me see the quickest, if you could be so kind.

Comment: @rschwieb   I'll comment on your answer. Tell me if I am writing nonsense!

Answer (score 13):

If you have an example for fields, you have an example for rings and abelian groups at the same time:

Take the field of rational polynomials $F(x)$ where $F$ is a field. The map $x\mapsto x^2$ defines a ring homomorphism of $F(x)\to F(x)$ which is necessarily injective (since $F(x)$ is a field) but not onto (its image is $F(x^2)$. The image is an isomorphic copy of $F(x)$ strictly contained in $F(x)$.

Of course, this means there is an infinite strictly descending chain of isomorphic copies...

Comment: We can make more complicated examples by taking for example for $F$ the algebraic closure of the rationals; and then looking at the field of rational functions of a countable set of algebraically independent trancendentals (or indeterminates) $t_1, t_2, \dots$, that is $K=F(t_1,t_2,\dots)$. This has, for any infinite subset of the transcendentals a corresponding isomorphic subfield. And if we take the algebraic closure of $K$ we get a field isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ do we nt?

Comment: @ancientmathematician You are probably building a copy of $\mathbb C$, but I'm still not clear on how it is shown this is a proper subring of a copy of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Well $K_1=F(t_2, t_3, \dots)\simeq K$ and is proper in $K$. Taking the algebraic closure of $K$ gives $\mathbb{C}$ in case when the $t_i$ are a transcendence basis for $\mathbb{C}$; it properly includes the algebraic closure of $K_1$ (as we don't pick up $t_1$), and this is also isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician What $F$ are you proposing? $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: [Lüroth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BCroth%27s_theorem) is a generalization of this result.

Comment: Stupid question -- why is it injective?

Comment: @ZacharySelk its kernel is an ideal and there is only one proper ideal in a field.

Comment: Wow, that's neat. Thanks.

Comment: @rschwieb : I mean the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. Sorry.

Answer (score 8):

$\mathbb{Z} \cong n \mathbb{Z}$ by way of the group isomorphism defined by $\varphi (k) = nk$, with $k,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ of course.

Comment: Of course $\varphi$ is *not* an isomorphism of rings if $n > 1$; it is only an isomorphism of groups.

Comment: Oh wow, how embarrassing. Editing now.